# Systemd (implicitly?) reloading

Tags: systemd

In my system on shutdown I see the following multiple messages in the (DLT) log file:

> [ 5632.345012] systemd[1]: Reloading.

The only way known to me to get this message is to explicitly restart systemd with "systemctl daemon-reload" command.
However neither searching files with grep nor even visually looking through the shutdown scripts for 'daemon-reload' does not give any appearance.

Is there any way that systemd is implicitly (i.e. self-) reloading under some circumstances?
Or may be any idea how to find the reason for these reloads?
Thanks.

Comment: What messages are you getting before the reloading message. Systemd (process 1) will be spawned by the kernel.

Comment: From systemd there is nothing special before, just few messages like:
"systemd[1]: Stopping Blahblah Service..."
"systemd[1]: Stopped Blahblah Service."